# Conditionally Change value of last column

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have a `data.frame` and want to change the value of the last column based on values of all previous (except the first one!) columns.

So if I have:

```
id v1 v2 v3 wei
1  NA NA NA  1
2  1  1  2   2
3  1  1  NA  1
4  1  1  1   3
```

I need to get

```
id v1 v2 v3 wei
1  NA NA NA  0
2  1  1  2   2
3  1  1  NA  1
4  1  1  1   3
```

Basically if I have all variables that start with "v" with missing values, wei needs to be 0. Same would happen for a df in which all values in the variables equal 0. So it should work for NA or 0.

Is this possible? I want to keep the same column called wei and just "update the value according to the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `rowSums` :

```
cols <- grep('^v', names(df))
df$wei[rowSums(is.na(df[cols])) == length(cols) | 
       rowSums(df[cols] == 0, na.rm = TRUE) == length(cols)] <- 0
df

#  id v1 v2 v3 wei
#1  1 NA NA NA   0
#2  2  1  1  2   2
#3  3  1  1 NA   1
#4  4  1  1  1   3
```

This will turn `wei` values to 0 where all "v" columns are `NA` or 0.

In case, there is a row with both 0 and `NA` we can do :

```
df$wei[rowSums(is.na(df[cols])|df[cols] == 0, na.rm = TRUE) == length(cols)] <- 0
```

Comment: what is a row has both zeros and NA?

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`(see notes below):

```
columns <- grep("^v", names(df))
df %>% 
   mutate(wei = ifelse(apply(df[columns],1, function(x) all(is.na(x))),0,wei))
  id v1 v2 v3 wei
1  1 NA NA NA   0
2  2  1  1  2   2
3  3  1  1 NA   1
4  4  1  1  1   3
```

**NOTE**

- This is likely to be very slow due to the usage of `apply`. It might be possible to use `rowwise` and/or `t`ranspose first or `pivot_*`.

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, v1 = c(NA, 1L, 1L, 1L), v2 = c(NA, 1L, 
1L, 1L), v3 = c(NA, 2L, NA, 1L), wei = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tidyverse way with *ifelse*

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text="id v1 v2 v3 wei
1  NA NA NA  1
2  1  1  2   2
3  1  1  NA  1
4  1  1  1   3", header=T)
colnames(df)
#> [1] "id"  "v1"  "v2"  "v3"  "wei"
df
#>   id v1 v2 v3 wei
#> 1  1 NA NA NA   1
#> 2  2  1  1  2   2
#> 3  3  1  1 NA   1
#> 4  4  1  1  1   3
df %>% 
  mutate(wei = ifelse(is.na(v1) & is.na(v2) & is.na(v3), 0, wei))
#>   id v1 v2 v3 wei
#> 1  1 NA NA NA   0
#> 2  2  1  1  2   2
#> 3  3  1  1 NA   1
#> 4  4  1  1  1   3
```

---

you can achieve this in base R in a similar way

```
# the same in base-R
df[is.na(df$v1)& is.na(df$v2)&is.na(df$v3),]$wei <- 0
df
#>   id v1 v2 v3 wei
#> 1  1 NA NA NA   0
#> 2  2  1  1  2   2
#> 3  3  1  1 NA   1
#> 4  4  1  1  1   3
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with, possibly not the most elegant solution but works for any number of columns that start with "v":

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~v1, ~v2, ~v3, ~wei,
  1 , NA, NA, NA, 1,
  2 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2, 
  3 , 1 , 1 , NA, 1,
  4 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 3)


df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(all_na = all(is.na(c_across(starts_with("v")))),
         all_zero = all(c_across(starts_with("v")) == 0)) %>% 
  mutate(wei = case_when(
    all_na | all_zero ~ 0,
    TRUE ~ wei
  )) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-all_na, -all_zero) # remove intermediate columns if needed, can be removed for debugging
```